# Function not changing variable (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Im making a Quiz game with swift and I have run into an issue. My RandomQuestionGenerator function doesn't seem to be changing my correctAnswer variable. I tested this by changing the if correctAnswer == 1 to if correctAnswer == 0 and the code when I press the button runs. Im guessing there is a stupid obvious solution but I can't figure it out.

```
var correctAnswer = 0 
func RandomQuestionGenerator(){

    var randomQuestion = 
    Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(fullQuestions.count)))
    var currentQuestion = fullQuestions[randomQuestion]
    var correctAnswer = currentQuestion.answer

    Label.text = currentQuestion.Question
    Button1.setTitle(currentQuestion.answers[0], for: .normal)
    Button2.setTitle(currentQuestion.answers[1], for: .normal)
    Button3.setTitle(currentQuestion.answers[2], for: .normal)
    Button4.setTitle(currentQuestion.answers[3], for: .normal)

    fullQuestions.remove(at: randomQuestion)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    appendQuestions()
    RandomQuestionGenerator()

}

@IBAction func Button1Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if correctAnswer == 1{
        RandomQuestionGenerator()
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `var currentQuestion = fullQuestions[randomQuestion]` is not a simple assignment. It's a variable declaration in the local code-block. Newly declared variable shadows the same names in the outer scope. Just remove `var` in that line. You should always distinguish variable declarations and assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OOPer said, the line `var currentQuestion = fullQuestions[randomQuestion]` does not reassign the variable, it "shadows" the global variable. This means that in the scope of the function, it is as if you have a separate variable with the same name. When you exit the function, the variable reverts to the value you declared in the beginning. To reassign the variable, use `currentQuestion = fullQuestions[randomQuestions]`, as that will not shadow, but simply reassign the variable

However, this may not be your problem. I noticed that in your `currentQuestion.answers` array, you have four values, with the indices 0,1,2, and 3. However, you named your buttons 1,2,3 and 4. It looks like this is why your if statement is `if correctAnswer == 1`. If the first answer is the correct one in this case, and currentQuestion.answer can either be 1,2,3 or 4, that may be your problem. If this is your problem, it can be fixed by replacing the if statements with `if correctAnswer = 0` for button1' `correctAnswer = 1` for button2, and so on

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it would be a stupid easy solution.